# What's the correct way to write a fetch event listener in a service worker for my PWA?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I'm writing a progressive web app and cannot figure out how to properly implement a fetch event listener that is supposed to serve cached files if they are already stored or fetch the file from the web if they are not in cache.  I believe this is the cache first approach.

`

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
    console.log(e.request.url);
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request).then((response) => response || fetch(e.request)),
    );
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
const assets = ["/", "styles.css", "app.js", "sw-register.js"];

self.addEventListener("install", event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open("assets").then( cache => {
            cache.addAll(assets);
        })
    );
});

// Stale while revalidate strategy
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then( cachedResponse => {
                const fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(
                     networkResponse => {
                        caches.open("assets").then( cache => {
                            cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
                            return networkResponse;
                        });
                    });
                return cachedResponse || fetchPromise; // cached or a network fetch
            })
        );
    }); 


// cache first strategy

// self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
//     event.respondWith(
//         caches.match(event.request)  
//             .then( response => {
//                 if (response) {
//                     // The request is in the cache 
//                     return response; 
//                 } else {  
//                     return fetch(event.request);
//                 }
//             })
//     );
// });
```